# Is it possible to specialize a function with member function pointers with convenient syntax for calling?

Tags: c++

Look at this non-compiling snippet:

```
struct Object {
    template <RETURN (OBJECT::*MEMFN)(PARAMETERS...), typename RETURN, typename OBJECT, typename ...PARAMETERS>
    void call() {
    }
};

struct Foo {
    void fn();
};

int main() {
    Object o;
    o.call<&Foo::fn>();
}
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is to have a function (`Object::call`), which is specialized with any kind of member function pointers, with convenient syntax to call.

The nearest solution I found is this, which is very ugly:

```
struct Object {
};

template <typename MEMFNTYPE, MEMFNTYPE MEMFN>
struct Caller;

template <typename RETURN, typename OBJECT, typename ...PARAMETERS, RETURN (OBJECT::*MEMFN)(PARAMETERS...)>
struct Caller<RETURN (OBJECT::*)(PARAMETERS...), MEMFN> {
    Object *object;

    Caller(Object &o) : object(&o) { }

    void call() {
        // I have the necessary information here: the member function pointer as template parameter, and a pointer to Object
    }
};

struct Foo {
    void fn();
};

int main() {
    Object o;

    Caller<decltype(&Foo::fn), &Foo::fn>(o).call();
}
```

Is there a better solution for this problem?

(The reason is I'm trying to do this is that I'd like to create wrapper functions (`call`) for other member functions)

---

Kerrek SB suggested using `auto`, I've tried this:

```
struct Object {
    template <auto MEMFN>
    void call();

    template <auto MEMFN, typename RETURN, typename OBJECT, typename ...PARAMETERS>
    void call<RETURN (OBJECT::*MEMFN)(PARAMETERS...)>() {
    }
};

struct Foo {
    void fn();
};

int main() {
    Object o;
    o.call<&Foo::fn>();
}
```

However, this doesn't compile (Do I need to add `MEMFN` differently to the template parameter list (instead of `auto MEMFN`?):

```
t2.cpp:6:7: error: parse error in template argument list
  void call<RETURN (OBJECT::*MEMFN)(PARAMETERS...)>() {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t2.cpp:6:52: error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘call<<expression error> >’ is not allowed
  void call<RETURN (OBJECT::*MEMFN)(PARAMETERS...)>() {
```

Comment: `template <auto F> void call();`, and then specialize.

Comment: Isn't that what `std::bind()` actually does?

Comment: Are you asking for `std::invoke`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks! I've tried it, and I got a compile error at specialization (I've updated the question)

Comment: @StoryTeller: oops, you're right. `template <auto>` is new to me, can you please tell how to fix it? I cannot simply add `MEMFN` there, because it doesn't compile (I suppose that MEMFN is not known there to the compiler, so I need to add MEMFN into the `template` list somehow)

Comment: TBH, I had no idea such a specialization is allowed. That was just the best educated guess I had. Maybe @KerrekSB can shed some more light on this.

Comment: You can't specialize function templates partially, so you need an auxiliary class template. Here's a [basic example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jnb6UfAmhIxbyyRz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested in the comments, if you accept C++17 solutions, then `auto` is your friend. And so are `<type_traits>` and `if constexpr`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct Object {
    template <auto MEMFN>
    void call() {
        if constexpr (std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(MEMFN)>)
            std::cout << "Is member\n";
    }
};

struct Foo {
    void fn();
};

int main() {
    Object o;
    o.call<&Foo::fn>();
}
```

The function body will only emit code that treats the parameter as a member function pointer if the type trait says it is indeed that. No specialization is required.

Comment: Thanks! Is is possible to create a version where `call` actually has the same parameter list as MEMFN has? "Reading" OBJECT/RETURN from MEMFN is possible with some template trickery, but I'm not sure how to read "PARAMETERS..." from MEMFN.

Comment: @geza - You could (in a few ways), but whether or not you should depends on how you want to use them.