# Is it possible to extract parameter types from a template <auto MEMFN>?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to create a standalone template function which has a template parameter `auto MEMFN` (a member function pointer), and has the same return and parameter types as MEMFN has?

So, if MEMFN's type is

```
RETURN (OBJECT::*)(PARAMETERS...)
```

then the desired function is this:

```
template <auto MEMFN>
RETURN foo(OBJECT &, PARAMETERS...);
```

My problem is how to extract `PARAMETERS...` from `MEMFN's type` (`RETURN` and `OBJECT` are easy to do).

So I can call this function like this:

```
Object o;
foo<&Object::func>(o, <parameters>...);
```

---

As for request from n.m., here is a stripped down example from an actual code:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename RETURN, typename OBJECT, typename ...PARAMETERS>
struct Wrapper {
    template <RETURN (OBJECT::*MEMFN)(PARAMETERS...)>
    RETURN foo(PARAMETERS... parameters) {
        // do whatever with MEMFN, parameters, etc. here, not part of the problem
    }
};

struct Object {
    template <auto MEMFN, typename RETURN, typename OBJECT, typename ...PARAMETERS>
    RETURN call(OBJECT &&object, PARAMETERS &&...parameters) {
        // here, MEMFN parameters and PARAMETERS must be the same

        // Wrapper actually not created here, it is accessed by other means
        Wrapper<RETURN, typename std::decay<OBJECT>::type, PARAMETERS...> w;

        return w.template foo<MEMFN>(std::forward<PARAMETERS>(parameters)...);
    }
};

struct Foo {
    void fn(int);
};

int main() {
    Object o;
    Foo f;
    o.call<&Foo::fn, void, Foo &, int>(f, 42);

    // this is wanted instead:
    // o.call<&Foo::fn>(f, 42);
}
```

Comment: Did you try typeid() ?

Comment: @v.chaplin: my problem is how to declare `foo`, so it will have the desired return/parameter types

Comment: What do you mean by "standalone"? Can the function template have external helpers, e.g. in a `detail` namespace? Can the function template be overloaded?

Comment: @ildjarn: yes, it can use external helpers, but its return type/parameter list must match MEMFN's. Maybe "standalone" is a bad term. I meant non-member function. What do you mean by overloading?

Comment: What if `Object::func` is overloaded? What if it is a template? Without putting some restrictions in place, I don't see how this is possible, as you would need some way to enumerate and store an overload set.

Comment: @ildjarn: then you can use the usual solution for that what we use when we want to pick a certain overloaded function: `static_cast` it. I don't see what do you mean by template. You need to instantiate it in this context, of course.

Comment: @ildjarn: maybe I don't understand what you say. With `o.call<static_cast<...>(&Foo::fn)>(...);`, I can select which `fn` I want to call. This is a rare thing, I don't care if the syntax is ugly here. I don't consider my request steep at all. If partial specialization were allowed for functions, or if we could refer to parameter packs somehow, it would be an easy task. These are both artificial limits of the language.

Comment: @ildjarn: It is perfectly fine that the answer to my question in the title is: "No, it is not possible".

Comment: I feel like there's a better answer to be had, the question is just horribly underspecified... _Why_ must `MEMFN` parameters and `PARAMETERS` be the same on the first line of `Object::call`? All that's being shown is using them to create a `Wrapper`, which is "*actually not created here*", so where does this requirement come from and what purpose does it serve? As with @n.m., I agree this seems too contrived to make any sense of... If the real work in `Object::call` could be delegated to a lambda inside samesaid function, that would be a starting point, but with the requirements as-is... ;-/

Comment: @ildjarn: underspecified because the "Why" doesn't explained? I don't understand this. Why does the "why"'s matter? I've posted a simple, well specified question. And just because it seems that there's no fine solution for this problem, people start asking "why do I want this". I don't understand this attitude. I want the same parameter list because I want to be able to point a memfn pointer to it, which has the same signature as MEMFN. But I don't think that this information helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Your requirements seem both arbitrary and unnecessary – of _course_ people want to make sense of it before attempting to answer. "*I want the same parameter list because I want to be able to point a memfn pointer to it, which has the same signature as MEMFN. But I don't think that this information helps to solve the problem.*" You're right, it doesn't – still pure XY.

Comment: @ildjarn: let's see a simpler case: not member function pointer, just simple function pointer. I'd like to create wrapper functions for existing functions. These wrapper functions will do something extra besides calling the wrapped function. And I want these wrapper functions compatible with the original function as much as possible. So the signature must be the same (because, I may want to point a function pointer to them). I don't want several wrapper functions created for each call. Because, maybe, there will be a static counter in the wrapper function, to count the number of calls.

Comment: @ildjarn: you threat this an XY problem, just because (maybe) it is not solvable.

Comment: Memfn-pointers do not make this problem any more complicated, and this problem appears easily solvable.. _except_ for the arbitrary "*here, MEMFN parameters and PARAMETERS must be the same*". Why there? Who knows. Certainly not to construct `Wrapper`, which was apparently shown for no reason at all since "*Wrapper actually not created here*". Meh, I'm done trying to get a better question; if the half-answer you got satisfies you, great. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: I've said a possible reason in my previous comment. Because I want it to be a perfect replacement in any possible way. How could I point a function pointer to the wrapper, if the signature is not the same? Why would the accepted answer be a half-answer? As I see, it actually does exactly what I need (not an elegant solution, but maybe the best one achieveable in the current limits of C++). It seems, that in C++, you can't create a template function which has the same parameter list as the template parameter. And instead of admitting that this is unfortunate...

Comment: @ildjarn: ... you say that the problem is XY instead. No, this seems to be a shortcoming of C++. For me, what I'd like to achieve, is completely reasonable. And, if this could be done in C++, you'd think this too, I think. But I don't want to argue about this further, to be honest. This is needed for my little-home-project, it is not that important. (I don't want to bash C++ at all, this is my favorite programming language, but if it has a shortcoming, I admit it, and I don't pretend that the problem is bad instead)

Comment: "*Because I want it to be a perfect replacement in any possible way.*" Thank you for admitting this is an XY problem – you want a perfect replacement, but what you asked for was a specific mechanism to approach it. What you want is possible, without doing it the way you asked. ;-] "*Why would the accepted answer be a half-answer?*" Needing to overload for arity post-C++14 is silly. "*It seems, that in C++, you can't create a template function which has the same parameter list as the template parameter.*" Right, but you don't _need to_ to get what you're asking for.

Comment: ... "*No, this seems to be a shortcoming of C++*" Not really. "*For me, what I'd like to achieve, is completely reasonable.*" Indeed it is, just not the way you asked to achieve it; but, SFINAE + perfect-forwarding will do the trick. Again, XY problem. ;-] I'll post some code in a little bit to see if it does what you want. :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you relax your demand on being standalone you can do something like:

```
#include <iostream>

template <auto MEMFN, class = decltype(MEMFN)>
struct S;

template <auto MEMFN, class Ret, class T, class... Args>
struct S<MEMFN, Ret (T::*)(Args...)> {
    static Ret foo(T &o, Args... args) {
        (o.*MEMFN)(args...);
    }
};

struct A {
    void foo(int a, int b) {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    S<&A::foo>::foo(a, 1, 2);
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AAL36z7rnQnhR2QR)

---

If no then you gonna have to have a patience to create a function overloads for each possible number of parameters:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <class, std::size_t>
struct DeduceParam;

template <class Ret, class T, class... Args, std::size_t N>
struct DeduceParam<Ret (T::*)(Args...), N> {
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Args...>>;
};

template <class>
struct DeduceResultAndType;

template <class Ret, class T, class... Args>
struct DeduceResultAndType<Ret (T::*)(Args...)> {
    using result = Ret;
    using type = T;
    static constexpr decltype(sizeof(T)) size = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <auto MEMFN, class DRAT = DeduceResultAndType<decltype(MEMFN)>, std::enable_if_t<DRAT::size == 1>* = nullptr>
typename DRAT::result  foo(typename DRAT::type o, typename DeduceParam<decltype(MEMFN), 0>::type param1) {
}

template <auto MEMFN, class DRAT = DeduceResultAndType<decltype(MEMFN)>, std::enable_if_t<DRAT::size == 2>* = nullptr>
typename DRAT::result  foo(typename DRAT::type o, typename DeduceParam<decltype(MEMFN), 0>::type param1, 
                                                  typename DeduceParam<decltype(MEMFN), 1>::type param2) {
}

struct A {
    void foo(int a, int b) {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    foo<&A::foo>(a, 1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Yep, thanks! But the reason of the question was the "standalone" part :)

Comment: @geza yes I was afraid that you gonna insist on that part ;)

Comment: Your second solution gave me an idea :) Maybe I can generalize this approach with `index_sequence`.

Comment: Actually, while I dislike adding overloads for each possible number of parameters, this approach does solve my problem. I feel similar when we didn't have variadic templates :) Anyway, if no better answer arrives, I'll accept this one (I need this construct at only 2 places in my code, so it is not a big deal to put ~10 overloaded functions there). (I couldn't solve this problem with `index_sequence`, as it boiled down to partial specialization, *again*)

Comment: @geza theoretically you could do this with `std::index_sequence` and little bit of sfinae like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JVqsa7sUH44nHB9s) but there is a huge chance your co-workers will kill you... ;)

Comment: OMG :) I'll have to take the time to actually decipher your solution. "ImplImplImpl".

Comment: :) yep the problem is with 2d compile time loop :)

Comment: If this actually works, and does what I need, I'll give you at least 10 upvotes :). I'll look at your other answers and blindly upvote them :) (fortunately, this is needed for my pet-project at home, so I'm safe from my co-workers)

Comment: @geza don't fall into hurraoptimism - it still does not solve your original problem. It just generates overloads of foo for given number of parameters from set `[0..N]`. `N` must be known beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes we can:

```
template <auto MemFn>
struct fooHelper;

template <typename Ret, typename Obj, typename ... Args, Ret (Obj::*MemFn)(Args...)>
struct fooHelper<MemFn>
{
    static Ret call(Obj& obj, Args... args) {
        return (obj.*MemFn)(args...);
    }
};

template <auto MemFn, typename ... Args>
auto foo(Args ... args)
{
    return fooHelper<MemFn>::call(args...);
}
```

Another way to define `foo` which doesn't introduce a brand new parameter pack is:

```
template <auto MemFn>
auto& foo = fooHelper<MemFn>::call;
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

struct moo
{
    int doit (int x, int y) { return x + y; }
};

int main()
{
    moo m;
    std::cout << foo<&moo::doit>(m, 1, 2) << "\n";
}
```

(Perfect forwarding omitted for simplicity)

Comment: The problem is that `foo` actually doesn't have the same parameters as MEMFN, but deduced from the actual call. I'd like to have the same parameters as MEMFN.

Comment: You can expose `fooHelper`'s Args pack, and static_assert that it matches `foo`'s Args

Comment: @Caleth but you cannot use `foo<&moo::doit>` without any arguments, say pass it to another function.

Comment: The function reference template variable approach just blown my mind! :)

Comment: @n.m.: thanks for the solutions, but unfortunately neither is good for me. Neither do what I needed: a standalone (non-member) function with MEMFN's parameter list. Maybe this cannot be done at all...

Comment: @geza Are you sure you are not having an XY problem?

Comment: @n.m.: Yes. My code work OK without `auto MEMFN`, by specify-ng RETURN, OBJECT, PARAMTERS... by hand. But it has an ugly syntax. That's what I'd like to make it convenient.

Comment: @n.m.: this is the precursor question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393159/is-it-possible-to-specialize-a-function-with-member-function-pointers-with-conve

Comment: @geza but you're aware that the function of your desire isn't actually standalone ;)

Comment: You state that you need a standalone (not a static member) function (not a function reference) with exact same arguments as some member function (not a perfect forward), but you are not saying why you pose all these requirements. Normally none of them should be needed in real code.

Comment: @W.F.: in that question, is not standalone, yes. But I think that it doesn't matter. But maybe I'm wrong. If I am, then I'm sorry :)

Comment: @W.F.: I think actually they have the same requirements, that's why I put the question this way, it was easier to formulate this way.

Comment: @n.m.: please check out the link I've said in the previous comment. This problem comes up when writing an `std::function` like class. And I need the memfuncptr as a template parameter, because I want to create a wrapper function for each memfuncptr (one wrapper function for each possible memfuncptr). This has the benefit that I can avoid memory allocation when there is no bound parameter (so it is more efficient than `std::function`)

Comment: @n.m.: my problem is more complicated than that, but it boils down to the question I've asked.

Comment: @geza I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to create an std::function-like class, you need a member function, not a standalone function. If you want to create a standalone wrapper, a function reference works for this purpose. I don't feel like this shooting in the dark is productive. Please show some real code and point out what should be fixed or improved.

Comment: @n.m.: Look at the linked problem. I'd like to access PARAMETERS... in `foo`. Sure, I can create a wrapper (like in your example), and use PARAMETERS... there. But I don't want to, because I need access Object's internals in foo. Sure, I can pass "Object &" to foo, but then `foo` cannot access Object's internals. Then I had to make the wrapper as a friend to Object. This is cumbersome.

Comment: @n.m.: I think that the asked problem is the same as the other. If you disagree, then I might post another question. But I don't think the solution will differ, because the same thing is needed for both: extracting PARAMETERS... from MEMFN without any wrappers, so PARAMETERS... can be the actual parameters for `foo`.

Comment: @n.m.: but maybe it is too much to ask from the language, because maybe partial specialization of functions is needed for the solution, which is not supported.

Comment: @geza I have no idea what you are talking about. I have no ides what the linked problem is about. Please show some **working** code you want to improve. You should have working code, because the requested component `foo` provides **only** syntactic convenience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155271/discussion-between-n-m-and-geza).